# Vertical alignment of text to the top-left of a cell in a table

Tags: tables, alignment

I'm very new to latex, and have been facing this issue for days now.
My aim is to code a calendar/to-do list for my forthcoming high school board examination. The code is pretty bare bones and simple, since I'm unaware of the potential of latex as of now. Here's an image of what my build looks like at the moment:[image: current calendar]

As you can see, the text is aligned to the left but not vertically. I would really appreciate it if my code could be modified to align the words to the top-left corner. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\center
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{6}

\begin{tabular}{|p{3.4cm}|p{3.4cm}|p{3.4cm}|p{3.4cm}|p{3.4cm}|p{3.4cm}|p{3.4cm}|}
\hline
Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday & Saturday & Sunday \\
\hline
Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday & Saturday & Sunday \\
\hline
Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday & Saturday & Sunday \\
\hline
Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday & Saturday & Sunday \\
\hline
Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday & Saturday & Sunday \\
\hline
Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday & Saturday & Sunday \\
\hline
Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday & Saturday & Sunday \\
\hline
Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday & Saturday & Sunday \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated but don't use `\center` use `\centering`. for the question remove (or reduce) `\arraystretch`  and end each row with `\\[50pt]` (or wherever)

Comment: Is that all what the table is going to contain? Are going to have more multi lined texts in that table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With use of the `tabularray` package is simple to get what you after:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {*{7}{X[l, h]}}, % left, top (header)
             rows = {ht=1cm}            % height of rows
             }
Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday & Saturday & Sunday \\
Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday & Saturday & Sunday \\
Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday & Saturday & Sunday \\
Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday & Saturday & Sunday \\
Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday & Saturday & Sunday \\
Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday & Saturday & Sunday \\
Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday & Saturday & Sunday \\
Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday & Saturday & Sunday \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `tabularray` is always such good and optimal solution :)